# Apposition et ponctuation

Tags: ponctuation, appositions

> *Rester c'est exister mais voyager c'est vivre*

On me demande comment ponctuer cette phrase.
D'instinct, j'aurais plutôt mis la virgule entre *exister* et *mais*.

Pourtant il me semble que *Rester* et *voyager* sont des appositions : première question : est-ce bien le cas ?

Si oui, alors il faudrait ponctuer ainsi :  *Rester, c'est exister mais voyager, c'est vivre.* Cela me gène car alors il me semble que la phrase est déséquilibrée. Il devrait y avoir une sorte de césure avant le *mais*.

Recherche faite, je me rends compte qu'il en faut bien une : d'après [le blog Images et mots](http://www.images-et-mots.fr/blog_images_et_mots/virgule-les-conjonctions-coordination/), *mais* est toujours précédé d'une virgule. Ouf, ça m'arrange !

Mais ce propos est nuancé par [etudes-litteraires.com](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic18253-mais-avec-ou-sans-virgule.html) où l'on peut lire

> On trouve, dans le Traité de la ponctuation française de Jacques Drillon :
>
> Page 171, la virgule :
>
> **2.** Avec une conjonction
>
> On fera peu d'erreurs si l'on place une virgule avant la conjonction dès lors qu'elle relie deux termes de fonction grammaticale différente ; et si l'on n'en met pas quand les deux termes qu'elle relie sont de fonction identique.

Aïe ! il semble bien que mes deux termes sont de fonction identique, ce sont les mêmes constructions !

Autre idée, mettre un point... Oui c'est un peu la solution de facilité, j'admets : *"Rester, c'est exister. Mais voyager, c'est vivre !"*. Grammaticalement, typographiquement, ça a l'air correct. Du point de vue du rythme par contre, c'est lourd !

Je devrais pouvoir dormir quand même, mais vos avis éclairés (ou pas) sur ces questions m'intéressent.

Merci.

Answer (score 2):

Pas de réponse systémique.

Première impression : *mais* est lourdingue, sentencieux, tautologique, manque totalement de créativité, bien franchouillard.

C'est un choix selon le contexte et l'intention de l'auteur, un choix cornélien pour Emmanuel : "reste et existe, voyage et vis..." ; sans conjonction la simplicité peut être savoureuse et ôter quelques épines inutilement douloureuses.

Si on ajoute *au présent* après le premier verbe il n'y a pas d'incompatibilité entre deux propositions qui envoient *ad patres* ce *mais* devenu incongru, libérant la phrase du blabla pontifiant et moralisateur pour accéder au Verbe libérateur qui éclaire les sens... l'essence des mots.

Comment: Le jugement me semble un peu rude, mais l'idée de supprimer le *mais* (_pourquoi n'y ai-je pas pensé ?_) me parait bonne :)... (je me rends compte que la phrase qui précède est construite sur le même modèle... avec le *mais* ^^)

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO - Cela ne sera pas exactement un jugement... même pas du tout... "(*1*) une recherche de la puissance de l'expression poétique". Selon que vous remplacez le  (*1*)  par : -- *mais*, on retombe dans une nouveau jugement qui annihilera rapidement l'ouverture poétique pour la circonvenir dans le connu, -- *peut-être* qui ouvre la recherche d'autres points de vue ignorés à ce jour..

Comment: ... je suis largué là...

Comment: "la simplicité peut être savoureuse" : mais où est-elle donc ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO ... on enlève la bogue alphabétique des mots, on glisse une pensée entre les coques polysèmes, le cerneau est au centre. Ensuite, c'est une question de goûts... qui ne se discutent pas. Libre à vous de sourire de cette réponse... à la noix !